# How to create rectangle with one shorter side?

Tags: android, shapes, android-drawable, drawrectangle

I'm trying to draw a rectangle with one shorter side like in the image below:

[image]

This is what I have for the moment, but my code doesn't work all I'm drawing is a black rectangle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: It's good to know. What the question is?

Comment: I updated my question. The question is How do i create a rectanglish Triangle like the one in the image in android ?

Comment: It's not rectangle or triangle on your image. What finally you want to draw? Trapeze?

Comment: Thats what I want to draw that black geometry figure

Comment: Draw rectangle + triangle

Comment: Could you help me do that ?

Comment: It would be easier to use images, is there a specific reason for using xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rotate a rectangle. Just adjust the negative padding to your desired size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-500dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-55"
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="100%">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hi tachyonflux. Could you please help me draw same shape but bottom line shorter instead of top?